# __consumer_offsets topic with very big partitions

Tags: apache-kafka

I am using Kafka 2.0.0
There are some partitions of the __consumer_offsets topic that are 500-700 GB and more than 5000-7000 segments. These segments are older than 2-3 months.
There aren't errors in the logs and that topic is COMPACT as default.

What could be the problem?
Maybe a config or a consumer problem? or maybe a bug of kafka 2.0.0?
What checks could I do?

My settings:

```
log.cleaner.enable=true
log.cleanup.policy = [delete]
log.retention.bytes = -1
log.segment.bytes = 268435456
log.retention.hours = 72
log.retention.check.interval.ms = 300000



offsets.commit.required.acks = -1
offsets.commit.timeout.ms = 5000
offsets.load.buffer.size = 5242880
offsets.retention.check.interval.ms = 600000
offsets.retention.minutes = 10080
offsets.topic.compression.codec = 0
offsets.topic.num.partitions = 50
offsets.topic.replication.factor = 3
offsets.topic.segment.bytes = 104857600
```

Answer (score 2):

Could be that you have application looping with different consumer groups evey time ?

You could use this command to look inside your _consumer_offsets topic, try to find out consumer
Group names repeats,  maybe you have some users creating many consumer groups with loops or running console consumers ...

```
echo "exclude.internal.topics=false" > /tmp/consumer.config
./kafka-console-consumer.sh --consumer.config /tmp/consumer.config \
--formatter "kafka.coordinator.group.GroupMetadataManager\$OffsetsMessageFormatter" \
--bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic __consumer_offsets --from-beginning
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to restart the cluster. It will resolve the issue, but it takes lot of time to rebalance because of the size of the topic.

There can be a Crash in [`log.cleaner.threads`](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#brokerconfigs_log.cleaner.threads) In your brokers. Restart the brokers restarts those treads and cleaning will start.

And `log.cleaner.threads` is default to one in kafka. Increase it and then if one tread crash, there will be another.

If this is the case, there should be logs about this in `server logs`

Comment: Already restarted but same problem. I don't see anything about this issue in the server logs. What other checks could I do? Is there a way to know when the compaction is done for that topic? It's very strange that there are thousands of segments older than 2-3 months for that topic. Thanks :)

Comment: Normally log cleaning runs in every 5 minutes. It is the default if you are not changed that. And cleanup.policy config for __consumer_offsets topic is default is `compact` and all segments older than delete.retention.ms should be compacted. So messages with same key will be compacted.

Comment: If you want to delete old segments, just change topic config to `delete` and reduce `retention.ms`. After old segments deleted, Change back the config for sure.

Comment: Ok, so the log cleaning runs in every 5 minutes and the segments older than delete.retention.ms ( 24hours in my case ) should be deleted. But in my case that doesn't happen and there are thousands of segments older than 2-3 months. What other could I check? I should figure out why this happen. I can't change the topic config every time. Thanks :)

Comment: After restarting broker, check server logs, there will be some errors if log cleaners crashed.

Comment: I have re-checked but no errors. The log cleaner doesn't start for some partitions.