# Apache Kafka and Log Compaction that doesn't run

Tags: apache-kafka

I am using kafka 2.0.0 and some partitions of the topic __consumer_offsets are very big ( 500-700GB ) and the segments are older than 2-3 months. There are no errors in the logs.

So, In which cases the log compaction doesn't start for some partitions?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [\_\_consumer\_offsets topic with very big partitions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67819409/consumer-offsets-topic-with-very-big-partitions)

Comment: Well, `log.cleaner.enable=false` is an obvious answer

Comment: @OneCricketeer it's true in my case :)

Comment: I'm not sure how this question is any different than your last one. You can set the log4j properties for the LogCleaner thread to TRACE or ALL to get more information about what is happening with it

Comment: @OneCricketeer it's different because I want to know why the compaction could not work for some partitions. I have partition of 20-30MB ans some partitions of 500-700GB :(

Comment: As mentioned in the other question answers, the thread(s) could be dying or stuck. AFAICT, the answers are going to be the same

Comment: @OneCricketeer How is possible that the threads die or stuck if I don't see errors in the logs?

Comment: Well, if the threads get into those states, you'd see no logs at all. Might be possible they stop without errors, although unlikely, but it's been known to happen from what I've heard